# AngularError - app.controller(...) is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I would like to understand why this code works but when it runs, I get a message: **app.controller(...) is not a function** and how can I fix it?

```
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('filtraPedido', []);
    app.controller('listdata',function($scope, $http){


        $scope.pedidos = [{'pedidoData':'15/01/2016 17:03:10','pedidoId':'603530313428-01','pedidoStatus':'Pagamento Pendente','pedidoValor':'3398','produtoId':'29','produtoNome':'Garrafa Personalizada (350 ml)','produtoPreco':'1400','produtoPagamento':'Boleto Bancário','produtoSeller':'Seller Name','hostname':'seller1','pedidoEstado':'RJ','pedidoCidade':'Rio de Janeiro','pedidoBairro':'Pechincha','utmCampaing': '','utmMedium': '','utmSource': ''}];

        $scope.sort = function(keyname){
            $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
        }

    })();

  </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/andremiani/kac912ep/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/kac912ep/3/

Just removed the `()` from line 94.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to immediately execute your app.controller registration as a function by using

```
app.controller('listdata',function($scope, $http){
    ...
})();
```

This is incorrect, since app.controller is NOT a function that can be invoked.  Simply remove the closing params.

```
app.controller('listdata',function($scope, $http){
    ...
});
```